# Router firewall rule to block all pings to a specific computer

Tags: router, firewall, mikrotik-routeros

I'm teaching myself basic home-networking using a Mikrotik "hAP ac" router.  I'm looking into firewall rules just now and I'm having real difficulty understanding why a very simple rule isn't working.

My test network is extremely simple:

RasPi (10.0.0.253) --- LAN cable --- Mikrotik (10.0.0.1) --- LAN cable --- PC (10.0.0.254).

To begin with, the PC can successfully ping the RasPi.  Just as a learning experiment I figured it would be a good idea to add a firewall to PREVENT the PC from being able to ping the RasPi, just so I can easily verify that the firewall rule is effective.

On the Mikrotik router I added a **forward** rule to **drop** **ICMP** packets to the **destination** address **10.0.0.253**.  Then I moved it up the list so that it was rule #1.  All the other firewall rules are factory standard for this device.  To my mind this should prevent ALL hosts from pinging the RasPi completely.

However, I can still successfully ping the 10.0.0.253 host from the PC.

The firewall filters table packet counters in the Mikrotik indicates that no particular rule is counting the ping packets, which leads me to believe that the implicit "let everything through" rule is just allowing them to happen.

Here's a dump of the firewall filters, which are factory standard apart from #1 which I added...

```
# jan/ 2/1970 12:44:34 by RouterOS 6.45.9
# software id = LPQ2-0CJJ
#
Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid, D - dynamic 
 0  D ;;; special dummy rule to show fasttrack counters
      chain=forward action=passthrough 

 1    ;;; --------------------------------------------------------------THIS ONE!
      chain=forward action=drop connection-state="" protocol=icmp 
      dst-address=10.0.0.253 log=no log-prefix="" 

 2    ;;; defconf: accept established,related,untracked
      chain=input action=accept 
      connection-state=established,related,untracked 

 3    ;;; defconf: drop invalid
      chain=input action=drop connection-state=invalid 

 4    ;;; defconf: accept ICMP
      chain=input action=accept protocol=icmp 

 5    ;;; defconf: accept to local loopback (for CAPsMAN)
      chain=input action=accept dst-address=127.0.0.1 

 6    ;;; defconf: drop all not coming from LAN
      chain=input action=drop in-interface-list=!LAN 

 7    ;;; defconf: accept in ipsec policy
      chain=forward action=accept ipsec-policy=in,ipsec 

 8    ;;; defconf: accept out ipsec policy
      chain=forward action=accept ipsec-policy=out,ipsec 

 9    ;;; defconf: fasttrack
      chain=forward action=fasttrack-connection 
      connection-state=established,related 

10    ;;; defconf: accept established,related, untracked
      chain=forward action=accept 
      connection-state=established,related,untracked 

11    ;;; defconf: drop invalid
      chain=forward action=drop connection-state=invalid 

12    ;;; defconf: drop all from WAN not DSTNATed
      chain=forward action=drop connection-state=new 
      connection-nat-state=!dstnat in-interface-list=WAN
```

Clearly something is missing from my configuration.  My understanding is that I shouldn't have to reboot or reset any hardware, changes should be immediate, at least from the Mikrotik side.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firewall rules only apply to packets that are routed at IP layer – but if both the sender and the recipient are in the same subnet, they will actually communicate directly at MAC layer, bypassing the router itself.

(In RouterOS, you can see that the physical ports are bridged under `/interface bridge port print`.)

Assuming both hosts are connected directly to the router using Ethernet cables (without another Ethernet switch providing a bypass), you would need to use the hAP's hardware switch ACLs to achieve such filtering – [refer to the docs](https://help.mikrotik.com/docs/display/ROS/Switch+Chip+Features) for limitations:

```
/interface ethernet switch rule add ...
```

Bridge ports having a 'H' flag indicating that they handle forwarding in hardware. But if this was a software bridge, such as that between Ethernet and Wi-Fi, then you would instead create rules at:

```
/interface bridge filter add ...
```

---

Alternatively, you might use switch port-isolation (together with proxy ARP), which forces the two hosts to always talk through the router.

A more common way to isolate devices would be creating two LANs or VLANs (with separate subnets), as they are isolated at MAC layer and have to go through the router and therefore through the IP firewall as well. This can be done by just removing one port from the bridge and configuring it to have a separate subnet.